# How can I Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content?

Tags: 7

I am using drupal 7 and Page speed in 82 for desktop on Google Page Insights. 
I am having some issues regarding eliminating render blocking js and css. 
How can I do this for aggregated js/css ? 
I know we cannot enable Leverage browser caching for external js.
I have used following modules:
1. Minify
2. Advanced CSS / JS Aggregation.

Please see the attached screenshot of Google Page Insights.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are not render blocking. That is the main Drupal's js and css aggregated. Because they have most of the site's js and css in them, they end up quite large, and that makes most optimizers detect them as problematic.

There is a high probability that you don't want to do anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Frontend sub-module and move JS to footer as a start.

Comment: If Frontend is a sub-module, what is the main module?

Comment: Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation

Comment: In Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation 2.18 I believe this sub-module is called `AdvAgg Modifier (advagg_mod)` (I have nothing with the name `frontend`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at the [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module. It allows you change the way the CSS and JS are compressed, bundled and optionally move (parts of) them to the footer.

It is quite an extensive module with lots of options and there are quite some tutorials out there, you can google for them. I once used a quite extensive one that I cannot find at the moment. So apologies for that.

Keep in mind that once you move things to the footer, not all Javascript might work anymore so you'll have to play with the settings a bit. And also if you move CSS to the footer, the browser will display an unstyled page and update it once the CSS is loaded. Depending on the size of your page and the CSS file, and your server configuration this can take noticeably long (and I find it ugly). So also do not forget that pagespeed is a tool and in no way science. Do not forget about the end user ;)